# default SELECT field limit in mysql with php?

Tags: php, mysql, json

We have a workflow system for offsetting work to other servers. The workflow job data has been growing quite big recently (for what we are used to). Storing anywhere up to 6MB of data in a json encoded array.

On the dev server in combination with phpmyadmin, we can pull out the contents of the `LONGBLOB` `job_data` field in its entirety, and view in a text editor to confirm that the entire json array is there.

When we try to extract the data with php it feels we are hitting some sort of default limit.

The query is nothing special:

```
SELECT
    workflow_ID,
    job_script,
    job_created_time,
    job_data
FROM
    workflow
WHERE
    job_started_time IS NULL
ORDER BY
    job_created_time
ASC
LIMIT 0,1
```

When printing the `job_data` row it is truncated. The example we are finding the issue with is 4.7mb in the db.

Has anyone ever had any other similar issue, is there a php mysql SELECT limit that i might need to increase? I could not find anything in google or here.

Comment: max_allowed_packet is pretty much the ultimate limit on how much data can hit the wire, in either direction.

Comment: Small side note: no need to use ASC in ORDER BY, since it's the default. If you prefer it for clarity, no problem--just thought I'd let you know.

Comment: how do you read this data? mysql, mysqli, pdo?

Comment: pdo Lashane, does this make a difference?  @MarcB thank you that is the key word i could not find.

Comment: @John yes, it makes difference, for mysqli you need to use `s` in bind_param to read blob, in pdo use `PDO::PARAM_LOB`

Comment: I always prefer to place ASC or DESC for clarity and speed when debugging.  @Lashane thanks for the tip!

Comment: check http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/178270-solved-blob-download-being-truncated-at-1mb/ it also could be the root cause

Comment: and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php try example with fpassthru

Comment: @Lashane i managed to get it all working! Thanks again. Added an answer below based on your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reponse to the help from the above commenters, @Lashane and @MarcB

The answer for me as i am using pdo:

Add to your [PDO __construct](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) options array `\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE` as found on [phpFreaks](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/178270-solved-blob-download-being-truncated-at-1mb/#post_id_1198399) by gizmola:

```
$this->db_con = new \PDO("mysql:host=$db_hostname;dbname=$db_database",
                                        "$db_username",
                                        "$db_password",
                                        array(
                                            \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
                                            \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE=> 16777216 /* 16mb max output to php from field */
                                        )
                                    );
```

For the extraction, add [`\PDO::PARAM_LOB`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php) to columns required (where `$column_number` in my case was 4, ie `job_data` for the OP query):

```
$statement->bindColumn($column_number, $lob, \PDO::PARAM_LOB);
```